# Stripe Cancel User Subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

Completely banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to cancel a user subscription.  I have been all through StackOverflow and cant seem to find anything to help.  Because I am fairly new to RoR the Stripe API only confuses me a bit more.  I do understand that I need to capture and save the user ID somehow before i can cancel.  I have not been able to figure this out...hence why i cant cancel subscriptions.  HELP PLEASE

Subscribe_controller.rb

```
class SubscribeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    unless (params[:plan_id] == '1' || params[:plan_id] == '2' || params[:plan_id] == '3')
      flash[:notice] = "Please select a plan to sign up."
      redirect_to new_subscribe_path
    end
  end

  def update
  # Amount in cents
  token = params[:stripeToken]
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => current_user.email,
    :card  => token,
    plan: params[:id]
  )

  current_user.subscribed = true
  current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
  current_user.save

  redirect_to demo_path, notice: "Your Plan was created. Enjoy the demo!"
  end

  def cancel_plan
    @user = current_user
    if @user.cancel_user_plan(params[:customer_id])
      @user.update_attributes(customer_id: nil, plan_id: 1)
      flash[:notice] = "Canceled subscription."
      redirect_to pricing_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error canceling your subscription. Please notify us."
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  def update_plan
    @user = current_user
    if (params[:user][:stripe_id] != nil) && (params[:plan] == "2")
      @user.update_attributes(plan_id: params[:plan], email: params[:email], stripe_id: params[:user][:stripe_id])
      @user.save_with_payment
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: "Updated to premium!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to update plan."
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
end
```

User_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def update
     if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
       flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
       redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
     else
       flash[:error] = "Invalid user information"
       redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
     end
   end

   private

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name)
   end
 end
```

Edit User Info Page

```
<div class="col-md-9 text-center">
    <h2>Manage Plan</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <%= button_to "Cancel my account", cancel_plan_path, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    <button class="btn-lg btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Update Plan</button>
  </div>
```

Routes.rb

```
get 'cancel_plan' => 'subscribe#cancel_plan'
resources :subscribe
devise_for :users
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that you have seen this before [stripe cancel subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription)

first you have to get the customer the you can find there subscriptions so you can delete it

```
# Definition 
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve({CUSTOMER_ID}) 
customer.subscriptions.retrieve({SUBSCRIPTION_ID}).delete 

# Example
require "stripe" 
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_fSaKtH5qZMmhyXiF7YXup2wz" 
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_5LXt66ikj5nYz5")
# customer.subscriptions returns a list of all subscriptions
customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_5TGMEBBALjNcD6").delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the input...yes and this is where I have trouble. What goes in place of the CUSTOMER_ID and SUBSCRIPTION_ID? Also I am assuming this is placed in it's own method entirely correct? I understand this concept fully but have no idea what to place in those 2 areas or in the .retrieve("cus_...") or .retrieve("sub_...")

Comment: if you log in to your stripe acc you will see the `CUSTOMER_ID` it loos like ***cus_5LXt66ikj5nYz5*** When I create a customer I like to save that in my DB

Comment: Yes. I thought I was doing that with the '''current_user.subscribed = true       current_user.stripe_id = customer.id   current_user.save''' calls I have under the update method. Is that part not correct? Because I can't seem to save them in my DB

Comment: Yes. Can you give me till 10AM central?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimate Answer

```
token = params[:stripeToken]
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => current_user.email,
    :card  => token,
    plan: params[:id]
  )
  current_user.subscribed = true
  current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
  current_user.stripe_subscription_id = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].id
  current_user.plan_name = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].plan.name
  current_user.save

  redirect_to demo_path, notice: "Your Plan was created. Enjoy the demo!"
```

Comment: how this is actually deleting and / or canceling a `Stripe::Subscription` ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this easier, you need to store the `stripe_id` and `subscription_id` in your database. Hence, after creating the columns `stripe_id` and `subscription_id` in your `User` model, you will have to save that:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
                                             email: params[:stripeEmail],
                                             source: params[:stripeToken],
                                             plan: params[:plan]
                                         })

subscription_id = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].id
user.update_attributes(stripe_id: customer.id, subscription_id: subscription_id)
```

Now you can always call the user's subscription since you have its id:

```
user = current_user
stripe_subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(user.subscription_id)
stripe_subscription.delete
```

If you only have the `customer_id` in your database, you can:

```
user = current_user
stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_id)
stripe_subscription = stripe_customer.['data'][0].delete
```